# Building ghc 7.6.3 on Ubuntu 13.04 leads to error in DynFlags.hs

Tags: 13.04, haskell

I'm trying to build ghc following the directions here: [How to install Haskell Platform for Ubuntu 13.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/286764/how-to-install-haskell-platform-for-ubuntu-13-04)

I keep getting:

```
HC [stage 1] compiler/stage2/build/DynFlags.p_o Killed make[1]: ***
[compiler/stage2/build/DynFlags.p_o] Error 137 
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I think I'm probably missing a dependency, but I have no idea which.

Comment: While compiling you don't run out of memory? It seems `make` is being killed by something (OOM killer?)

Answer (score 1):

Yup Salem had it right. It was an OOM issue. I increased the servers RAM from 512MB to 1024MB, and the problem was solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem building GHC-7.8.2 on a Raspberry Pi: the compiler ran out of memory while doing `compiler/main/DynFlags.hs`. But switching off optimisations on that particular step apparently keeps the memory use low enough so it works:

> $ "/usr/bin/ghc" -hisuf hi -osuf  o -hcsuf hc -static  -H32m **-O0**  -package-conf libraries/bootstrapping.conf  -package-name ghc-7.8.2 -hide-all-packages ...

Wheras `make` invokes it as `...  -static  -H32m -O  -package-conf ...`.

After that, you can resume the normal (optimised) build of the other modules by running `make` again. I suppose the performance doesn't suffer too badly if that one module isn't optimised, in particular since it doesn't look like it really does anything critical – only, [it's just really big!](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.4.2/html/libraries/ghc-7.4.2/src/DynFlags.html)

Comment: Mind, that did not get me through the entire building process... I eventually had to make more memory available anyway ([via swap to external HD](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/70/how-to-set-up-swap-space)) when `compiler/hsSyn/HsExpr.lhs` wouldn't compile even in `O0`.