# Installing Haskell Platform from source on Ubuntu 13.04: Can't find OpenGL

Tags: software-installation, haskell

I'm attempting to install Haskell Platform 2013.2.0.0 on a fairly fresh Ubuntu 13.04, using the instructions here: [How to install Haskell Platform for Ubuntu 13.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/286764/how-to-install-haskell-platform-for-ubuntu-13-04)

I've installed the extra packages mentioned in the comments, but the `configure` step generates an error related to OpenGL not being found.
Here it is:

```
> ./configure
# Omitting some output
# ...
checking for zlibVersion in -lz... yes
checking GL/gl.h usability... yes
checking GL/gl.h presence... yes
checking for GL/gl.h... yes
checking for library containing glEnd... no
configure: error: The OpenGL C library is required
```

Strangely, it can find the OpenGL headers, but it can't find `glEnd`.
Any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: I have the same problem, but I don't have sudo access on the server. What can I do ?

Answer (score 1):

Install the following:

```
sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dev
sudo apt-get install libglc-dev
sudo apt-get install freeglut3-dev
sudo apt-get install libedit-dev
sudo apt-get install libglw1-mesa libglw1-mesa-dev
```

Then

```
./configure
#now build
sudo make install
cabal update
```

source: http://nathanwiegand.com/blog/2009/07/haskell-platform-on-ubuntu.html‎

Comment: I already had these packages installed, so this did not help :(