# How to install haskell for Ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: 13.10, software-installation, haskell

I am trying to do `sudo apt-get install haskell-platform` but get only package not found message. What do I actually need to do?

Comment: This might be of help. http://askubuntu.com/questions/286764/how-to-install-haskell-platform-for-ubuntu-13-04

Comment: The Ubuntu version in this question is different. It requires installing ghc with `sudo apt-get install ghc` but it doesn't work for me. It says it can't be installed because of unsatisfiable dependencies `libgmp-dev` and `libbsd-dev`. Could it be this this works only for 13.04?

Comment: Actually I don't know. I provided this link for general information and there was a good chance for it to work on your problem. Sorry that it didn't work out!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please, could you put some of your time to read https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers?

Comment: Did you try `sudo apt-get update` before you did `sudo apt-get install haskell-platform`?

Answer (score 1):

It's really weird because `haskell-platform` is actually properly packaged for Ubuntu Saucy (13.10), see the dedicated [package page](http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/haskell-platform).

I tested installation using the following command and it installed correctly:

```
sudo apt-get install haskell-platform
```

The unsatisfiable dependencies `libgmp-dev` and `libbsd-dev` that you mentioned in your question are both available main, I'd suggest to (re-)enable both main and universe archives and refresh the package list:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main universe restricted multiverse"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install haskell-platform
```

Note: `apt-get install -f` will just ensure that there's no broken package on your system.